# Can I make Grid Layout stretch like an HTML table does?

Tags: apache-flex

I have use the mx:Grid layout component to layout some form elements in a manner very similar to an HTML table. However, the result does not stretch out horizontally when you resize the app like an HTML table would. How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the width and height of the Grid element to a percentage value.

I'm using a Grid on one of my main applications, and I've set the width/height to 100% and it resizes just fine.

You'll likely need to set the width and height of the rows and items (GridRow and GridItem) as well, depending on how you want the rows/columns to resize.

**Edit** if you're creating the Grid programmatically (e.g. in a .as file), you'll need to set these values as percentages as follows:

```
var grid:Grid = new Grid();
grid.percentWidth = 100;
grid.percentHeight = 100;
```

Comment: What I missed was setting the widths in the rows and items. Thanks.